# Extension field: a question about algebric extension field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

***Def.***  Let $K\subseteq L$ be a field extension, and let $B$ be a subset of $L$. We denote by $K(B)$ the smallest subfield of $L$ containing both $K$ and B.

> **Question.** Suppose that we have proved that $$L=K(B).$$ Can I conclude that $L$ is algebraic over $K(B)$?

Comment: If $L$ is *equal* to $K(B)$, then yes, every field is algebraic over itself

Comment: You are saying that $L=K(B)$. Of course the extension $K(B) \subseteq L$ is algebraic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it is good for you to see it.

Let $K$ be field and $u\in K$, then $u$ is the root of  $x-u\in K[x]$, therefore, algebraic over $K.$